# Como se referenciar ao próprio atributo de um objeto JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array de objetos:

```js
    window.matObj = [
    
     {
      id: 11,
      x: aleatorio(3,9),
      y: aleatorio(3,9),
      resposta: (window.matObj[0].x + window.matObj[0].y),
      enunciado: window.matObj[0].x + " + " + window.matObj[0].y
     },
    
     {
      id:12,
      x: aleatorio(3,9),
      y: aleatorio(3,9),
      resposta: (window.matObj[1].x + window.matObj[1].y)
     },
    
    ];
```

Porém, ao executar a aplicação, dá o seguinte erro:

> Error in undefined: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'window.matObj[0]')

Acredito que estou me referenciando aos atributos de cada objeto (`x` e `y`) de maneira errada.

Como seria a maneira correta?

Comment: Também gostaria de poder fazer isso, deixa o código mais legível

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto acontece porque você esta tentando acessar dados de um objeto que ainda nem foi criado, e assim não tem como ser referenciado por ele mesmo. Você deve cria-lo primeiro para depois obter valores.

```
window.matObj = [

    {
        id: 11,
        x: aleatorio(3,9),
        y: aleatorio(3,9)
    },

    {
        id:12,
        x: aleatorio(3,9),
        y: aleatorio(3,9)
    },
];

window.matObj[0].resposta = (window.matObj[0].x + window.matObj[0].y);

window.matObj[0].enunciado = window.matObj[0].x + " + " + window.matObj[0].y;


window.matObj[1].resposta = (window.matObj[1].x + window.matObj[1].y);
```